# Yarn AM está encerrando trabalho ao enviar um trabalho remoto ao cluster

Tags: spark

Eu tenho procurado por um identificador em um problema sem muitas pistas. Qualquer ajuda que me aponte para a direção certa será enorme.

Qualquer ajuda será de grande valor.

Estou rodando um *Hadoop Cluster* usando *emr-5.25.0* com as seguintes aplicações: *Hive* 2.3.5, *Spark* 2.4.3, *Oozie* 5.1.0. E também tenho um *client* *emr* com a mesma configuração.

Todos os ambientes estão executando no *CentOS*.

Eu enviei alguns trabalhos do *Spark* localmente no *cluster* com sucesso.

Quando submeti remotamente os trabalhos *Mapeduce* remotamente, recebi um *AM Error*:

```
AM fails the job with the error:

           SecretManager$InvalidToken: appattempt_1564396684837_0011_000002 not found in AMRMTokenSecretManager
```

Eu procurei por `/var/log/oozie` no *client* e no *cluster* sem mensagens incomuns.

Aqui está o conteúdo do `workflow.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<workflow-app xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:1.0" name="shell-wf">

    <start to="spark-node"/>

    <action name='spark-node'>
        <spark xmlns="uri:oozie:spark-action:1.0">
            <resource-manager>hdfs://xxx:8032</resource-manager>
            <name-node>hdfs://xxx:8020</name-node>
            <master>${master}</master>
            <mode>${mode}</mode>
            <name>snapshot-${table_name}</name>
            <jar>${continuous_ingestion}/workflow-snapshot.py</jar>
      <spark-opts>--py-files ${continuous_ingestion}/release/continuous_ingestion_release.zip --files ${continuous_ingestion}/${env}.cfg --conf spark.executorEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6 --conf spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.PYSPARK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.6 --conf spark.driver.memory=4g --conf spark.driver.maxResultSize=1g --conf spark.driver.cores=1 --conf spark.executor.instances=1 --conf spark.executor.cores=2 --conf spark.executor.memory=4g --conf spark.eventLog.enabled=false --conf spark.sql.broadcastTimeout=36000 --conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=1 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=30 --packages org.lz4:lz4-java:1.4.0 </spark-opts>
            <arg>${table_name}</arg>
            <arg>${env}</arg>
        </spark>
        <ok to="end" />
        <error to="fail_spark" />
    </action>
    <kill name="fail_spark">
        <message>Bash action failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name="end"/>
</workflow-app>
```

A saída do `log` de tarefas no `cluster` foi:

> Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): appattempt_1564396684837_0011_000002 not found in AMRMTokenSecretManager.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1489)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.registerApplicationMaster(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.registerApplicationMaster(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:107)
>       ... 20 more
>   Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken: appattempt_1564396684837_0011_000002 not found in AMRMTokenSecretManager.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateException(RPCUtil.java:53)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.instantiateIOException(RPCUtil.java:80)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.ipc.RPCUtil.unwrapAndThrowException(RPCUtil.java:119)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.finishApplicationMaster(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:94)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:409)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:163)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:155)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler$Call.invokeOnce(RetryInvocationHandler.java:95)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:346)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy8.finishApplicationMaster(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.AMRMClientImpl.unregisterApplicationMaster(AMRMClientImpl.java:472)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.async.impl.AMRMClientAsyncImpl.unregisterApplicationMaster(AMRMClientAsyncImpl.java:187)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.unregisterWithRM(LauncherAM.java:352)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.run(LauncherAM.java:278)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM$1.run(LauncherAM.java:153)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1844)
>       at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherAM.main(LauncherAM.java:141)
>   Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.security.token.SecretManager$InvalidToken): appattempt_1564396684837_0011_000002 not found in AMRMTokenSecretManager.
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1489)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1435)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1345)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:227)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:116)
>       at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy7.finishApplicationMaster(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.impl.pb.client.ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.finishApplicationMaster(ApplicationMasterProtocolPBClientImpl.java:92)
>       ... 19 more

Comment: Tem como traduzir para portugues? Foi postado em uma comunidade em portugues.

Comment: Editei e traduzi a pergunta, quem puder, colabore para ajudar o usuário.